# Not getting the correct answer for an infinite limit problem

Tags: calculus, limits

The problem:

$\lim _{ x\to -\infty  } \frac { \sqrt { 9x^{ 6 }-x }  }{ x^{ 3 }+8 }$

My answer: $3$

What I did:

$\\ \lim _{ x\to -\infty  } \frac { \sqrt { x^{ 6 }(9-\frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 5 } } ) }  }{ x^{ 3 }(1+\frac { 8 }{ { x }^{ 3 } } ) } \\ \\ \lim _{ x\to -\infty  } \frac { { x }^{ 3 }\sqrt { 9-\frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 5 } }  }  }{ x^{ 3 }(1+\frac { 8 }{ { x }^{ 3 } } ) } \\ \lim _{ x\to -\infty  } \frac { \sqrt { 9-\frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 5 } }  }  }{ 1+\frac { 8 }{ { x }^{ 3 } }  } \\ $

And since

$\\ \lim _{x\to-\infty} \frac{1}{{x}^{5}}\quad =\quad 0\\ \\ \lim _{x\to -\infty} \frac{8}{{x}^{3}} \quad =\quad 0\\ \\ $

plugging in $0$ for above values...

$\\ \frac {\sqrt{9}}{1} \quad =\quad 3\\$

The correct answer is apparently $-3$, I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason you might suspect that's the right answer is that you can numerically evaluate the expression for some large value of $x$, say, $-1000$, and see that the numerator will give you roughly $\sqrt{9 \times (-1000)^6}$ which is a positive value. On the other hand, the numerator after you've done a little algebra,  $(-1000)^3 \sqrt{9}$ is a negative number. So that very first step, where you extracted $\sqrt{x^6}$ as $x^3$, was an error. You can check that for $x = -1$, for instance. Letting $y$ denote $x^3$, you're trying to replace $\sqrt{y^2}$ with $y$...but the correct replacement is $|y| = |x^3|$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  use that $\sqrt{x^6}=|x^3|$